# How to parse PDF text into sentences

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm wondering how to parse PDF text into sentences, I've found a great variety of solutions here, but quite frankly I do not understand them or they do not solve the problem.

The text I'm trying to parse is IMF reports, and found that the best libary to use is pdfminer. The ultimate goal is to perform sentiment analysis on the reports.
link to text: https://www.imf.org/en/Publications/WEO/Issues/2019/03/28/world-economic-outlook-april-2019

The biggest problems I've encountered are the diverse layout and filtering them, such as frontpage, table of content, graphs etc. The second problem is special characters and characters that it can't read properly making them apostrophes.

Here is what I've got and what I'have tried:

Def Parse_PDF(file) is used to read the PDF

def text_to_sentence() is supposed to convert the text into a list of sentences, put doesn't.

The other two solutions I have found here, for the purpose of reading the PDF, but haven't found them to work properly on the text as explained above. What am I missing here, what can be done for this?

```
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser
from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFTextExtractionNotAllowed
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.pdfdevice import PDFDevice
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.converter import PDFPageAggregator
import pdfminer
import PyPDF2 as pdf
import nltk

def Parse_PDF(file):
    filename = '/Users/andreas/Desktop/Python/Portfolio/Text_analasis/IMF_Publications/{}.pdf'.format(file)
    Myfile = open(filename, mode='rb') #Opens PDF  
    pdfReader = pdf.PdfFileReader(Myfile) #Reads file
    parsedpageCt = pdfReader.numPages #Get's number of pages
    count = 0
    text = ""
    #The while loop will read each page
    while count < parsedpageCt:
        pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(count)
        count +=1
        text += pageObj.extractText() #Extracts the text
    report = text.lower()
    return text


def text_to_sentence():
    tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
    data = Parse_PDF('text')
    return '\n-----\n'.join(tokenizer.tokenize(data))


fp = open('/Users/andreas/Desktop/Python/Portfolio/Text_analasis/IMF_Publications/text.pdf', 'rb')
rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
laparams = LAParams()
device = PDFPageAggregator(rsrcmgr, laparams=laparams)
interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
pages = PDFPage.get_pages(fp)

for page in pages:
    print('Processing next page...')
    interpreter.process_page(page)
    layout = device.get_result()
    print(layout)
    #for lobj in layout:
        #if isinstance(lobj, LTTextBox):
            #x, y, text = lobj.bbox[0], lobj.bbox[3], lobj.get_text()
            #print('At %r is text: %s' % ((x, y), text))

fp = open('/Users/andreas/Desktop/Python/Portfolio/Text_analasis/IMF_Publications/text.pdf', 'rb')

# Create a PDF parser object associated with the file object.
parser = PDFParser(fp)

# Create a PDF document object that stores the document structure.
# Password for initialization as 2nd parameter
document = PDFDocument(parser)

# Check if the document allows text extraction. If not, abort.
if not document.is_extractable:
    raise PDFTextExtractionNotAllowed

# Create a PDF resource manager object that stores shared resources.
rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()

# Create a PDF device object.
device = PDFDevice(rsrcmgr)

# BEGIN LAYOUT ANALYSIS
# Set parameters for analysis.
laparams = LAParams()

# Create a PDF page aggregator object.
device = PDFPageAggregator(rsrcmgr, laparams=laparams)

# Create a PDF interpreter object.
interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)

def parse_obj(lt_objs):

    # loop over the object list
    for obj in lt_objs:

        # if it's a textbox, print text and location
        if isinstance(obj, pdfminer.layout.LTTextBoxHorizontal):
            print("%6d, %6d, %s" % (obj.bbox[0], obj.bbox[1], obj.get_text().replace('\n', '_')))

        # if it's a container, recurse
        elif isinstance(obj, pdfminer.layout.LTFigure):
            parse_obj(obj._objs)

# loop over all pages in the document
for page in PDFPage.create_pages(document):

    # read the page into a layout object
    interpreter.process_page(page)
    layout = device.get_result()

    # extract text from this object
    parse_obj(layout._objs)
```

Comment: You will probably find it easier to parse the HTML (you linked to it) than a PDF. PDF text is not necessarily laid down such that letters adjacent to each other on the page are adjacent in the file. You may have to recreate the page graphically in your program to be able to get multi-glyph constructs like "words"

Comment: Would a solution in R be useful to you?

Comment: @DMU not really since I have no experience in R, but thanks for your consideration!

Comment: @mpez0 I see, it's quite a task to beat the data into shape if it comes from a pdf?

Comment: It _may_ be difficult. PDF text _may_ be easily extractable as readable plain text, but it _may_ also be a scattered list of characters (each with its coordinate position on the page) with the character's position in the list having little or no relationship to its page position. It _may_ also be the case that some or all whitespace is not part of the extractable text...

Comment: @mpez0 Is there any way to know if it may be difficult or not, like any clue in the metadata or something similar?

Comment: Think about the problem that PDF is designed to solve. It puts shapes on a page. There's no reason for the instructions for those shapes to be in any particular order.

Comment: @misterbutter No metadata clues as far as I've been able to tell. Even ignoring "images" that are text, PDF text areas are <coordinate, glyph> lists that are arranged at the convenience of the generating software.